# multidimensional array in java- need to display students, scores, averages and more stuff

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

help please; im very confused. I need to make a multidimensional array for the class Im taking and it isn't going very well. These are the directions:
[these are the directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYEFz.png)

[example of what the arrays should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ7s4.png)

this is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hw {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfStudents;
    int assignments;
    int amtOfScores;
    int valueOfScores;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of students in the class: ");
    numOfStudents =  in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of assignments: ");
    assignments = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the values of all of the exam scores:");
    valueOfScores = in.nextInt();
    amtOfScores = numOfStudents* assignments;
    }
}}
```

Comment: No. You need a single array of `Student`(s). That is a tabular output, and does not require multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch there are supposed to be 3 sheets so wouldnt that make it a multidimensional array? I'm new to java so I'm still learning. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ElliotFrisch yes, I learned about them a little bit in small detail. but in the instructions my teacher said "Your program should declare a multidimensional 3D array"....etc. which is why I'm confused. it is in the first picture I attached

Comment: That's horrible. But fine. Do that then. `String[][][] table = new String[numOfStudents][assignments][valueOfScores];`